# Working on my own Gutenberg image block and facing issue while resizing height and width

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, gutenberg-blocks

I need to change the height and width of my image through the Gutenberg setting ( inspector control ). However, it's not allowing me to change the height and width.

This is my block.js file to set attributes:-

```
"mediaURL": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "width": {
            "type": "number"
        },
        "height": {
            "type": "number"
        },
        "scale": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "aspectRatio": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "size":{
            "type": "number"
        },
        "slug":{
            "type":"string"
        },
        "imageWidth": {
            "type": "number",
            "default": 200
        },
        "imageHeight": {
            "type": "number",
            "default": 200
        },
```

This is my edit.js file:-

```
  import { InspectorControls, __experimentalImageSizeControl as ImageSizeControl } from '@wordpress/block-editor'; 
 
   import { PanelBody, Panel } from '@wordpress/components';

   const {
       attributes: {height, width, imageWidth, imageHeight, slug, scale },
       setAttributes,
    } = props;

const onChangeSize = (value) =>{
    setAttributes({
        width: value.width,
        height: value.height,
    })
}


return (
    <>
    {/* Side bar setting for image block start */}
    <InspectorControls>

        <Panel>
            <PanelBody title="Setting">

            <ImageSizeControl
                 onChange={ onChangeSize }
                 width={ width}
                 height={ height}
                 imageWidth={ imageWidth }
                 imageHeight={ imageHeight }
            />

            </PanelBody>
        </Panel>
    </InspectorControls>
   </>
```

The width and height of the image should be change from the inpector control pannel